# Is there any pattern to define responsive layout with Angulardart components?

Tags: dart, angular-dart, angular-components

Is there any pattern to define layout (pre-defined css) with Angulardart component similar to [Flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) or [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/grid.html)?

I would like to find responsive behavior for components, for example, `material-applayout`, `material-list-item`, and others.

Comment: I guess not . . . .

Comment: Would there be any suggestions for the best way forward in AngularDart? Use a particular CSS library (any indication?) or set CSS "on hand" for component's layouts.

Comment: That depends on your requirements. Taking some parts from MDL might work for you

Comment: Are you asking if the Dart angular_components package offers a framework for the layout of your application? It does include some components that you can combine for a layout of your choosing like drawers and the app_bar. https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/tree/master/lib/app_layout

Comment: App Layout it's nice. But I am looking for a pattern to apply responsive behavior with angular_components in Dart. Like [Angular JS - Layout](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/introduction)